# execute CUDA kernel few times

Tags: cuda

I have problem with execute CUDA kernel few times. Somethings is wrong with environment in my code. First time code works properly, second time during clean up environemnt before third call there are random crashes.
I think for some reason I have memory corruption. Crashes occurs sometimes in CUDA driver, sometimes simple printf crashes or cheap, kernel32.dll. I suppose that I have problem with memory management in my code.

What should be done before again kernel execution ?

This code works when I execute one time. 
I'm using CURAND to initialize random generators. 
Here is my code:

```
    #define GRID_BLOCK 64
    #define GRID_THREAD 8
    #define CITIES 100
    #define CIPOW2 101
    int lenghtPaths = GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD;
    int cities = CITIES; 
    //prepare CURAND 
    curandState *devStates;
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devStates, GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD*sizeof(curandState)));
    /* Setup prng states */
    setup_kernel<<<GRID_BLOCK ,GRID_THREAD>>>(devStates);
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
        fprintf(stderr, "CURAND preparation failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    //copy distance grid to constant memory 
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cdist, dist, sizeof(int) *CIPOW2*CIPOW2);
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_pathsForThreads, lenghtPaths * cities * sizeof(int)));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_results, GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD * sizeof(int)));
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        int* pathsForThreads;
        pathsForThreads = (int*)malloc(lenghtPaths * cities * sizeof(int));
        pathsForThreads = PreaparePaths(Path, lenghtPaths, cities);
        CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(dev_pathsForThreads, pathsForThreads, lenghtPaths *cities*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        GPUAnnealing<<<GRID_BLOCK ,GRID_THREAD >>>(dev_pathsForThreads, devStates, iterationLimit,temperature, coolingRate, absoluteTemperature, cities,d_results);
        CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) 
            fprintf(stderr, "GPUAnnealing launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        h_results = (int*) malloc(GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD * sizeof(int));
        //Copy lenght of each path to CPU 
        CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(h_results, d_results,  GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        //Copy paths to CPU 
        CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(pathsForThreads, dev_pathsForThreads, lenghtPaths *cities*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        //check the shortest path                       
        shortestPath = FindTheShortestPath(h_results);
        fprintf (stdout, "Shortest path on index = %d value = %d \n", shortestPath, h_results[shortestPath]);
        for (int i = 0; i < GRID_BLOCK*GRID_BLOCK ; i++)
            Path[i] = pathsForThreads[shortestPath*CITIES +i]; 
        free(pathsForThreads);
        free(h_results);
    }
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(dev_pathsForThreads));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(d_results));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devStates));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceReset());
```

Comment: You need to show complete code or a short reproducer for people to help you. And `GRID_BLOCK == lenghtPaths` and `GRID_THREAD == cities`?? You are allocating `lenghtPaths * cities * sizeof(int)` bytes for `dev_pathsForThreads` and `GRID_BLOCK*GRID_THREAD * sizeof(int)` for `pathsForThreads`

Comment: I update the code with the defines structures and `malloc` declaration

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea:

```
    pathsForThreads = (int*)malloc(lenghtPaths * cities * sizeof(int));
    pathsForThreads = PreaparePaths(Path, lenghtPaths, cities);
```

If the call to `PreaparePaths` assigns some other value to `pathsForThreads` than what was assigned to it by the `malloc` operation, then later when you do this:

```
    free(pathsForThreads);
```

You're going to get unpredictable results.

You should not reassign a pointer that you're subsequently going to pass to `free` to some other value.  The man page for free indicates:

> ```
>   free() frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must  have  been
>    returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc().
> ```

So reassigning the pointer to something else is not allowed if you intend to pass it to `free`